# Adding a number into a string in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

I have the following code snippets:

```
student_t students[10];
char *name = "Student";
```

and this one

```
for (int i = 0; i < STUDENT_COUNT; i++) {
    students[i].id = i;
    students[i].note = 1.0 + (i%4);
    strcpy(students[i].name, name);
    students[i].name[7] = (char) i + '0';  
    students[i].name[8] = '\0';           
}
```

I dont understand this part:

```
    students[i].name[7] = (char) i + '0';  
    students[i].name[8] = '\0';
```

What is happening here?

Comment: `(char) i + '0'` That converts an `int` single digit to an ascii character. `0` becomes `'0'`, `1` becomes `'1'`, etc.

Comment: It's writing the *character* which represents the single digit value `i` (with `'0' + i`) and then terminating the string (with `'\0'`).

Comment: If `i` is a number from `0` to `9`, then it can be represented by ASCII characters from `'0'` to `'9'`. And in order it to do so, it needs to get offset by the ascii value of `'0'`.

Comment: Can you please show the definition of `STUDENT_COUNT`? If it is greater than 9 then that code won't work.

Comment: Presumably that is the hard-coded `10` in `student_t students[10];`. Please do fully use your macros – there should be a *single* definition of sizes, limits etc where possible.

Comment: Thank you for your help !!!

Comment: Please note that this is a very old-fashioned, low-level way of dealing with a very limited concept of "text". Handling modern text properly in plain C is not easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `students[i].name[7] = (char) i + '0';`

`i + '0'` converts the numbers 0 to 9 into the ASCII encoding of those numbers.<sup>[1]</sup>

- `0` ⇒ `'0'`
- `1` ⇒ `'1'`
- ...
- `9` ⇒ `'9'`

---

> `students[i].name[8] = '\0';`

C strings must be terminated by a NUL character (`'\0'` aka just `0`).

---

The buffer to which `name` points:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 'S' | 't' | 'u' | 'd' | 'e' | 'n' | 't' |  0  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

`students[i].name`:

1. Initial:

   ```
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+- ... -+-----+
   | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? | ??? |       | ??? |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+- ... -+-----+
   ```
2. After `strcpy(students[i].name, name);`:

   ```
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+- ... -+-----+
   | 'S' | 't' | 'u' | 'd' | 'e' | 'n' | 't' |  0  | ??? | ??? |       | ??? |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+- ... -+-----+
   ```
3. After `students[i].name[7] = (char) i + '0';` (when `i==4`):

   ```
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+- ... -+-----+
   | 'S' | 't' | 'u' | 'd' | 'e' | 'n' | 't' | '4' | ??? | ??? |       | ??? |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+- ... -+-----+
   ```
4. After `students[i].name[8] = '\0';`:

   ```
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+- ... -+-----+
   | 'S' | 't' | 'u' | 'd' | 'e' | 'n' | 't' | '4' |  0  | ??? |       | ??? |
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+- ... -+-----+
   ```

---

1. On an EBCDIC machine, it will produce the EBCDIC encoding of the number.